# ScrollView not scrolling in .net MAUI

Tags: scrollview, maui

I created below code with ScrollView in .NET MAUI, when trying to scroll nothing happens. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
        <!--    <local:NavigationControl x:Name="_accountPage"/> -->
            <ScrollView VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
            <StackLayout Margin="5" Spacing="20">
               
               --- some content 

                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Regards,
Ali

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The scroll view vertical options need to be FillAndExpand

Comment: It worked after setting the scroll view vertical options to "FillAndExpand", thank you Steven.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. ScrollView doesn't scroll on iOS until I move to landscape and then back to portrait. I'm running Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.3.6 with Xamarin.iOS version 16.0.0.75. My target is net6.0-ios14.5. Minimum target is 13.0.

Comment: Place the ScrollView inside a Grid.

Comment: This answer is not valid anymore. See [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/7346#discussioncomment-2794122)

Answer (score 9):

I also came across this issue while update a program to MAUI.  I looked into the Microsoft documentation @  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/scrollview?view=net-maui-7.0

Within this I found the following:

**ScrollView as a child layout**

A ScrollView can be a child layout to a different parent layout.

A ScrollView will **often be the child of a Grid**. A ScrollView requires a specific height to compute the difference between the height of its content and its own height, with the difference being the amount that the ScrollView can scroll its content. When a ScrollView is the child of a Grid, it doesn't receive a specific height. The Grid wants the ScrollView to be as short as possible, which is either the height of the ScrollView contents or zero. To handle this scenario, the RowDefinition of the **Grid row that contains the ScrollView should be set to** *. This will cause the Grid to give the ScrollView all the extra space not required by the other children, and the ScrollView will then have a specific heigh

So in the end I moved by ScrollView from a stack like referenced in the code above into a grid with a row height of * for the ScrollView and auto for my other componence.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<ContentPage.Content>
<ScrollView VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
        <StackLayout>
        <!--    <local:NavigationControl x:Name="_accountPage"/> -->           
            <StackLayout Margin="5" Spacing="20">
               
               --- some content 

                </StackLayout>            
        </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It is solved by setting the scroll view vertical options to FillAndExpand as Steven mentioned in his answer below.

Answer (score 1):

scrollview have a size is scrollview's size, it also have a size is child size, when child size is biger than scrollview size, it need scroll. But when scrollview in stacklayout, stacklayout determine size according to child itself size, so scrollview size = child size, so you don't need scroll. That mean you need give a size to scrollview, or set it on other layout, such as Grid, Grid size is fixed,it will give child a fixed size.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It is solved by setting the scroll view vertical options to FillAndExpand as Steven mentioned in his answer below.

Comment: @yangzhou Can you expand on this? My app works fine on Android. When I open the iOS app, the scroll doesn't work. I then have to turn the phone into landscape mode. I then turn back to portrait and the scroll works. I tried the FillAndExpand method. That didn't work. I'm using this code. https://github.com/cemahseri/MauiFinance/blob/main/Views/MainPage.xaml Thanks!

Comment: @Dumber_Texan2 Did you find a solution? I am seeing the same thing

Comment: @SamuelJames Yes, make sure you are using an ObservableCollection. See my Answer for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Is it Android where your scrollview is not working? If so this issue has been noted here:

[ScrollView doesn't work properly on Android. #7590](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7590)

It suggests that it's been fixed in a service release. I have not seen that fix come to fruition yet - maybe we're still waiting for that next service release.

Comment: Yes in Android, thanks for the note.

Answer (score -1):

I was using a List. Make sure you use an ObservableCollection.

Something like this.

```
public ObservableCollection<OverviewItem> OverviewItems
    {
        get { return _items; }
        private set { _items = value; OnPropertyChanged("OverviewItems"); }
    }
```

Here is the method.

```
    public async Task<ObservableCollection<OverviewItem>> GetData()
    {
        var itemList = new ObservableCollection<OverviewItem>();

        //Do something

        return itemList; 
    }
```

Call it like this.

```
OverviewItems = await GetData();
```